# HAXM not installing due to system requirements

Tags: virtualization, haxm

While Installing HAXM i got this error
[HAXM error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y61KM.png)
[HAXM error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFVf0.png)

I have virtualization enabled and i don't see hyper -v option in window features. I have tried each and every solution but nothing has worked.
Any help is highly appreciated.
[Virtualization enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFzjq.png)

Comment: Perhaps HAXM requires Intel VMX and doesn’t support AMD virtualization.

Comment: Yes i have downloaded Android Emulator from SDK components and its working fine

Answer (score 0):

**The short answer**

HAXM does not support AMD.

**The full answer**

HAXM installer checks if your system meets it's requirements and outputs the results. When you move the error messagebox on your first screenshot away from the dialog box, you will see these.
Check what requirements are not met and find out what's the possible reason at HAXM [Windows Installation Environment Check and Configurations](https://github.com/intel/haxm/wiki/Windows-Installation-Environment-Check-and-Configurations) page.

Comment: Thanks issue has been resolved HAXM doesn't install on AMD processors for that we can download Android Emulator from SDK components nad it's working fine thanks for your help